# How to substract Table1 values from Table2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1 contains ColumnA, Table2 contains ColumnA and ColumnB.

How do I remove(delete) rows in Table2 that contain ColumnA values in both tables?

Comment: `DELETE B FROM TableB B JOIN TableA A ON A.ID = B.ForeignID;`? Think we need more explanation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete rows from table2 where the ColumnA value is also found in table1:

```
delete from table2
where ColumnA in (select ColumnA from table1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `EXISTS`

```
delete t
from table2 t
where exists
(
 select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.columna=t.columna
)
```